# How to use php conditional statement for hyperlink in table cell

Tags: php

I have a table where record are fetched from MySQL. The code is as below:

```
<li>
  <table style="width:100%;">
    <tr>
      <?php
        $test_method_3 = FetchTestMethodsByMethodTest(3, $t['id']);
        $test_method_1 = FetchTestMethodsByMethodTest(1, $t['id']);
        $test_method_7 = FetchTestMethodsByMethodTest(7, $t['id']);
      ?>        
      <td>
        <a href="/dna-testing/test/<?= $t['seo_url']; ?>/<?= $t['id']; ?>/">
          <?= $t['test_name_search'];?>
        </a>
      </td> (This will create a link for record)
    </tr>
  </table>                
</li>
```

I want to use condition before `<td><a href="/dna-testing......</td>` fireup. So that if `$test_method_3` and `%test_method_7` is empty then it should link with another page like `"http://www.mydomain.com/action.php"`

How can I achieve this. I am not PHP pro but learner. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
<td>
<?php if(empty($test_method_3) && empty($test_method_7)): ?>
    <a href="http://www.mydomain.com/action.php"">
        <?=$t['test_name_search'];?>
    </a>
<?php else: ?>
    <a href="/dna-testing/test/<?= $t['seo_url']; ?>/<?= $t['id']; ?>/"><?=$t['test_name_search'];?></a>
<?php endif; ?>
</td> (This will create a link for record)
```

Comment: @dakar, yours one working but problem is "somethingelse.html" shows only hyperlink with out record name. Record name should come from ['seo_url'] field. I use a pdf file link for "somethingelse.html" link. could you please help me again. thanks.

Comment: @Kortoa I'm not sure what you mean? Where do you want seo_url? In the link or as the text?

Comment: @dakar, correction! record name comes from ['test_name_search'] not ['seo_url']. Thanks

Comment: @dakar, I want record name should come from ['test_name_search'] fild as text of link. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Simply like this:

```
<?php if(empty($test_method_3) && empty($test_method_7)) { ?>
    <td><a href="http://www.mydomain.com/action.php">...</a></td>
<?php } else { ?>
    <td><a href="/dna-testing/test/<?= $t['seo_url']; ?>/<?= $t['id']; ?>/"><?= $t['test_name_search'];?></a></td>
<?php } ?>
```

Note that this [`empty()`](http://php.net/empty) method will check for an empty string "", NULL, FALSE, and a few other 'empty' possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

try as below :

```
     <li>
           <table style="width:100%;">
           <tr>
            <?php
$test_method_3 = FetchTestMethodsByMethodTest(3, $t['id']);
$test_method_1 = FetchTestMethodsByMethodTest(1, $t['id']);
$test_method_7 = FetchTestMethodsByMethodTest(7, $t['id']);
?>      
            <td>
   <?php if($test_methode == "" AND $test_methode_7 == "") { ?>

   <a href="http://www.mydomain.com/action.php"">This link</a>

 <?php } else { ?>

 <a href="/dna-testing/test/<?= $t['seo_url']; ?>/<?= $t['id']; ?>/"><?=   $t['test_name_search'];?></a>
```

```
   </td> (This will create a link for record)
          </tr>
    </table>                
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
<?php if(empty($test_method_3) && empty($test_method_7)){?>
        <td><a href="/dna-testing/test/<?= $t['seo_url']; ?>/<?= $t['id']; ?>/"><?= $t['test_name_search'];?></a></td>//different link
<?php } else {?>
<td>
<a href="/dna-testing/test/<?= $t['seo_url']; ?>/<?= $t['id']; ?>/"><?= $t['test_name_search'];?></a></td>
<?php } ?>
```